# get data without "then" method / get and use directly

Tags: json, react-native

I have a JSON URL and I get the JSON from that and export to other js file.

After that when I want to use it I have to use

js1:

```
export const getData = () => fetch(state._WEB_SERIVICE_URL+'get_config')
  .then(response => response.json())
```

js2:

```
export const B2 = getData().then(data => {
    alert(data.main_color+"*");
    return data.main_color 
      /* do what you want to do in promise resolve callback function */
})
```

js3

```
B2.then(data => {
      alert(data+"*2"); // I want to get it directly...
})
```

How to access `B2.data` without `.then(`?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `await` for that

```
const response = await fetch(state._WEB_SERIVICE_URL+'get_config')
console.log(response)
return response
```

For more, you can check document [Networking](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/network)

Comment: thank  you let me check , it's seem the  await most in to  the async function , yes ?